# CDC calling SSIS real time in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: ssis, oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2, cdc

I need to push data from SQL Server 2008 R2 in real time to Oracle 11g. The solution proposed are to use CDC and SSIS.

What I understand is CDC is just like a system table which captures changes in registered tables. SSIS is more like an ETL tool.

What I understand is that someone or process need to execute SSIS for pulling data from CDC and then pushing it to Oracle tables.

So do we need to schedule it?? Or there is some other mechanism such that it will be called automatically when there is data is CDC tables.

If it need to be scheduled then it’s not real time (more like near real time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much latency is in real time? 0 seconds? For SQL > Oracle that's impossible.

Is 1 second acceptable? what about 5 minutes?

You need to accept some kind of latency, you'll never get real time from SQL to Oracle. I work with a system transferring data from many systems (including SQL Server) into Oracle but it has about 10 minutes latency. It applies all changes found in the last ten minutes. It could probably be improved but there is actually no requirement to.

In answer to your question, yes, something has to call schedule SSIS (possible a scheduler)

You could technically call a SSIS package from a table trigger so that it runs instantly that a change is made, but a package takes 1000's of times longer to run than it does to make changes to a table so that's not going to work.

So practically speaking you have to accept some change queuing at the source and some change queuing at the target.

If you need much less latency you should consider a queue type setup (SSIS not involved) where SQL Server changes are posted to some kind of queue on the Oracle side and processed by Oracle

To reduce load on the SQL Server source, use native SQL Server CDC http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx rather than manually created triggers and log tables.

Whatever mechanism you use to transfer changed data to the subscriber (Scheduled SSIS, send to a queue... whatever), the impact is the same. SSIS gives you no performance benefits.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My previous solution was to use trigger based solution. Trigger on a table which enqueue primary key (service broker), once dequeued it will push the data to oracle. This was real time or comparitively real time than sceduler cdc & SSIS.

Comment: Also do you know which will(CDC/SSIS or (Trigger/Service Broker) put more load on system??

Comment: It's hard to say. SSIS is a batch solution which has large impacts at less frequent intervals and a trigger/queue is a trickle solution which has frequent small impacts. What are your observations from your previous solution? Is the source system sensitive to impacts or is your target system sensitive?

Comment: I was asked to propose a design considering minimal impact on source system(SQL Server 2008 R2). I was proposing trigger solution + pulling data from oracle considering less impact on source system. But I am not able to convince him that SSIS with frequent scheduler + pushing data will have higher impact on source system. He is saying its internal to MsSQL server, it can take that.

Comment: If you use 'native' SQL Server CDC http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx instead of manually created triggers and log tables I expect there will be less impact as you are reading straight from the log rather than executing special triggers etc.

Comment: But then we would require SSIS right? and we need to then schedule SSIS every less internal to get real time data.

Comment: There are other ways to transfer data besides SSIS. Yes if you use CDC there is a batch element to it. You either transfer in batch (scheduled) or you push using triggers into a queue but triggers will impact your source database.

Comment: When I say trigger, we will also use service broker(queue) so that the trigeer is not impacted. When you say impact on source system what impact we are talking about?

Comment: Creating a trigger on a table (that calls a queue or logs to a table) creates a little more 'work' when altering data. Theoretically this 'work' can add up (causing an impact), or stop the data change. That's two ways that adding triggers to your source system can impact the source system. If instead you use native CDC (which does not use triggers) and a periodic batch process to push the CDC out to a target, your source system is only impacted when the batch is run.

Comment: But pushing CDC via SSIS say every 5 min will impact the source system as well? What are the other ways beside SSIS and but still uses CDC?

Comment: Everything impacts the source system but triggers will impact it the most. Native CDC gives you a recordset of changes. You can apply those changes to the target use many ways besides SSIS. Send to a queue. drop in a flat file. `OPENROWSET`. We're going around in circles here. Seperate the data transfer (SSIS) from the actual CDC mechanism (native CDC or manual trigger CDC)